# Get an user data from Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, authorization

I have added comments on my web-site with authorization through most popular social networks. In `comments` db-table I have next fields:

```
...
type    ENUM('fb', 'gl', 'vk', 'tw'...)
user_id VARCHAR(64)
comment VARCHAR(5000)
...
```

When page has loaded, javascript gets all unique pairs "type/user_id" and gets user data from web (logo and name) with differnt GET queries like next one:

```
GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/{USER_ID}?requestMask.includeField=person.photos%2Cperson.names&fields=addresses%2CageRange%...
```

Everything works fine, except Facebook. It demands access_token, which is limited in time.

And this is the problem!

I have two solutions:
1. Keep user data (logo and name) in the database and periodically refresh the data.
2. Generate the access_token on my server and pass it to javascript.

I don't like both of them. I am asking for help. What is the easiest way to get data from Facebook by GET-query? Where can I get access_token in javascript?

Comment: _"Where can I get access_token in javascript?"_ - from the JavaScript SDK - as long as the user is logged into Facebook, and has logged into your app to grant it permission to access their basic profile info before.

Comment: That is the point that I don't need logged users at all. The page is watched by many people and most of them aren't logged. I want just get commentators' name through my "app_id", nothing more. And I wouldn't use FB JS SDK due to it is too big for my purpose. A simple GET-query works fine in other cases, but not in FB (

Comment: Well the you can only use your app access token, and that means you must do it server-side, because your app access token should never be exposed in client-side code.

Comment: I can't believe it due to I can view any FB user with simple GET-guery:

    https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id={USER_ID}

And I even don't have to have an account. But it is unhandy to parse whole the page in JavaScript. I suppose there is simple way to get the data in JSON.

Comment: Believe it. The official UI and the API are two completely different things. (And it would not be "unhandy" to scrape the actual page - but in fact not even allowed.)

Comment: It is insane! ))
I have an unique user id. I can't make it up, I have got it from an user himself. I am able to see the data on his page (name and logo). But I can't get the same data from the API??? Wtf ))) Why all other APIs let me do it?

Comment: You can get their profile picture (via redirect; only API endpoint that does not require any access token), but that's all you can get.

Comment: I can write API that I need in a few weeks. All what I need is VPS. I don't need even Facebook resolution. Isn't it silly that FB doesn't provide such functionality.